# project directory structure python data

Tags: python, database, data-structures, directory-structure

I have a python project with the following directory structure

```
|-- package_name/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- lambda_function.py
|   |-- ...
|
|-- database/
|   |-- data.json
```

And I'm using data.json file on my package to initialize some objects.

I would like to split my current data file on multiple json files because there are too much information group on one single file

Something like :

```
|-- database/
|   |-- A/
|   |   |-- a.json
|   |   |-- b.json
|   |-- B/
|   |   |-- c.json
|   |   |-- C/
|   |       |-- a.json
|   |       |-- b.json
```

I don't want to make a real database because data will not move, there are just here to initialize my objects.

Question :
How can I do to have multiple json files to clarify the code, but a simple way to use them as if it was a single one.
I would like to know the best practices on how manage that kind of data on a python projects.

Comment: well you can can read json files and join all in one dict

Comment: If you have too much information to store it in a json file, but still want to use it as a single config, you should considere using the `configparser` module which can natively process configuration data splitted in numerous files. If you can accept a 2 levels directory (section: key-value pairs) it can be a nice way. Anyway, I am afraid that the question is not precise enough for this site...